# TS2304: Cannot find name <class name>

Tags: typescript, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I updated my nuxt.js to latest version (2.4.2). When i update it will return **Cannot find name**  when i do **npm run dev**, but before in nuxt.js 1 it was find. I do my code like this:

*assets/scripts/b.ts*

```
export default class B {}
```

*assets/scripts/a.ts*

```
import B from "assets/scripts/b"
```

*tsconfig.json*

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
"target": "es5",
"lib": ["dom", "es2015"],
"module": "es2015",
"moduleResolution": "node",
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"noImplicitAny": false,
"noImplicitThis": false,
"strictNullChecks": true,
"removeComments": true,
"suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
"allowJs": true,
"baseUrl": ".",
"types": ["node"],
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types",
  "types/*"
]
},
"compileOnSave": true
}
```

module: *typescript.js*

```
module.exports = function () {
// Add .ts & .tsx extension to Nuxt

this.nuxt.options.extensions.push('ts', 'tsx')

// Extend webpack build
this.extendBuild(config => {
// Add TypeScript
config.module.rules.push({
  test: /\.tsx?$/,
  loader: 'ts-loader',
  options: { appendTsSuffixTo: [/\.vue$/] }
})

// Add .ts extension in webpack resolve
if (! config.resolve.extensions.includes('.ts')) {
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.ts')
}

// Add .tsx extension in webpack resolve
if (! config.resolve.extensions.includes('.tsx')) {
  config.resolve.extensions.push('.tsx')
}
})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use nuxt-ts with nuxt 2.4.
Please see release notes https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/releases/tag/v2.4.0